# Where are hhvm command line flag definitions found?

Tags: macos, phpunit, hhvm, perf

When running phpunit 4.5 with hhvm inside docker sometimes it crashes the container. I'm not sure if I should alter the way I run hhvm on the command line or not. Are there any standards for running hhvm on the commandline?
So I'd like to get more familiar with hhvm's command line flags and definitions. Where can I find documentation on this?

I read on the https://codeascraft.com/2015/04/06/experimenting-with-hhvm-at-etsy/ that they used a tool called 'perf'. I don't seem to generate any perf.map files from the commandline. Browser requests have generated perf.map files though.

FYI
I've installed hhvm-nightly-dbg on ubuntu:14.10 to try to get more information when hhvm hangs on the command line.

My setup consists of the following

- Mac osx Mavericks
- Vagrant 1.7.2
- VirtualBox 4.3.26
- coreos-vagrant (running all containers with docker 1.5)

The containers are running

- Redis:2.8.19
- Mysql:5.1.73
- hhvm-nightly-dbg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In our Ubuntu packages, configuration lives in `/etc/hhvm/*.ini`. Both files are loaded and combined when running in server mode.
- Many INI options from PHP are available in HHVM with the same name. The HHVM-specific INI options are [listed on the HHVM wiki](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/INI-Settings); many are unfortunately missing documentation, though all of the important ones are there. There's a huge array of configurability here; you'll never need 99% of these.
- `/etc/init.d/hhvm` controls the exact command-line options; you shouldn't need to modify this, set INI options instead.
- Although you can pass any INI option to HHVM on the command line when not running in server mode, the mapping between command-line and INI syntax is weird and inconsistent for historical reasons. I'd strongly recommend just passing `-c path/to/config.ini` as a command line option instead, and just writing all your options in INI files. You can pass `-c` more than once; the files will be combined.